# Javascript code for adding rows in a table copies the data in the cell to new row

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am making a form that will be used in Internet Explorer.  I have a table that has the capability to add rows dynamically.  However, when you click the add row button it copies all of the data in the cell to the new row.

Anyone know a trick for this.  Chrome works just fine.

```
<table id="divDocument" class="tftable" border="1">
<tr>
<td style="width:20px;"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
<td style="width:150px;"> <textarea id="txtDocument" class="textarea required" alt="Document/Item/Process" title="Document/Item/Process" style="border: none; width: 100%; height:100%;"></textarea></td>
```

```
</table>

function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
if(rowCount<=6){ 
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
        case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "";
            break;
        case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
        case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
        case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
        case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
        case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
        case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
    } 
    }
} else{alert("Please submit another CCR with remaining items.  Thanks!");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add textarea type and loop with your variable i:

```
<script>function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    if(rowCount<=6){
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            switch(newcell.childNodes[i].type) {
                case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].innerHTML = "";
                    break;
                case "textarea":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].value = "";
                    break;
                case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].value = "";
                    break;
                case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].value = "";
                    break;
                case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].value = "";
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].checked = false;
                    break;
                case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[i].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else{alert("Please submit another CCR with remaining items.  Thanks!");}
}</script>
```